# Como capturar el xpath de un texto o una clase con selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Buen día, lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de capturar el xpath de un texto que esta incluido en un div, pero siempre recibo el mismo error no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"xpath que trato de capturar"}

tengo el siguiente código

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time


url = 'https://www.bbva.com.co/personas/productos/inversion/fondos/pais.html'
#Controlador de google schrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\seburiti\Anaconda3\Lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
#Pagina a la que se le hara wescraping 
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
src = driver.find_element_by_id("content-iframe_copy").get_attribute("src")
driver.close()

driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\seburiti\Anaconda3\Lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver2.get(src)
driver2.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
imp = driver2.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='description']").text
```

La primera parte del código la tengo hecha porque lo que quiero extraer, el número 16.284,58 esta contenida en un iframe, agradecería mucho su ayuda, estoy aprendiendo.

url del iframe : https://bbva-cells-files.s3.amazonaws.com/cells/apps/bbva_es_ficha_global_am_cells/bbva_ficha_global_am_cells_co/master/cellsapp/prod/vulcanize/index.html#!/fichaco/CCAPAISCB

url original : https://www.bbva.com.co/personas/productos/inversion/fondos/pais.html